Docker Compose: dynamically change the image architecture based on running host machine
quick question: is it possible to dynamically change the image's arch based on the host's machine instead of create 2 separate docker compose file?
Currently I have 2 files:
For arm64 (osx)
services:
  typesense:
    image: docker.io/typesense/typesense:0.25.2-arm64
    container_name: typesense
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8108:8108"
    volumes:
      - ./typesense-data:/data
    command: '--data-dir /data --api-key=xyz --enable-cors'

For non arm64
services:
  typesense:
    image: docker.io/typesense/typesense:0.25.2
    container_name: typesense
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8108:8108"
    volumes:
      - ./typesense-data:/data
    command: '--data-dir /data --api-key=xyz --enable-cors'

The only difference here is the image, and ideally running them e.g. docker compose up -d then let the engine decide which arch is appropriate in the host's machine instead of using docker compose -f <FILE> up -d.

The image used in that example is already a multi-platform image. To check the arch of image, one can check the running container:
# docker inspect <container-id> or docker inspect <your-image>
docker inspect typesense/typesense:0.25.2

see docker ref: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform
devops thread: https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/19307/24024
devtalk thread: https://forum.devtalk.com/t/docker-compose-dynamically-change-the-image-architecture-based-on-running-host-machine/155452/10?u=jaeyson

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, if so, I've outlined one here for you
https://github.com/devobs-ob/stackoverflow/tree/main/docker/DynamicImage-78493215
TLDR:

create a script that retrieves the type of arch, store it in a variable, and let it choose the image based on the value
replace the image with a variable in the image field of the Dockerfile.

You can find instructions and the scripts in the Github repo linked above. Hope this helps and thanks for sharing your question.
-- Ob
edit
When running the script: instead of ./filename.sh, run source filename.sh in order to capture the variable in the host machine.

yes that's the closest thing. I was planning to add the script as entrypoint, but forgot that starting the compose file will check the env first

I'm not sure if there's a use case where it's not a multi-platform image in order to use the bash script way.
